# Conditional wrong when trying to match strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have code that gets the users locale and store it in a variable. I then have a conditional that checks if the locale matches a specific value - see the picture below:

[image]

Above you can see the value of locale is "sv-SE".

I then have a conditional too see if the value of locale is "en-US" || "en-GB" in a if statement.

I would except the statement to be false, since the value of locale is "sv-SE" in this case, and does not match the string values in the statement - but the if conditional becomes true and the code inside the if statement executes. Why?

Comment: `x == "a" || "b"` should be `x == "a" || x == "b"`. Having a non-empty string on its own in a conditional will always be `true`

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: `"en-GB"` is a truthy value so your if-statement will always match, since it doesn't compare against anything variable.

Comment: When you do `"en-US" || "en-GB"`, the outcome here is always `en-US`.  OR  returns the first truthy value or the last one if no truthy value is found. So your comparison is always doing `if(locale === "en-US")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the comparison to the locale variable...
Try to do this and see if it works.

```js
if (locale === 'en-US' || locale === 'en-GB') {
   ...
}
```